# Properties of the mean value theorem derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. Fix $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and recall the MVT

$\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} = f'(\delta_x)$ where $\delta_x \in (c,x)$.

> What can we say about the "function" $\delta:\mathbb{R}_{x>c} \to \mathbb{R}?$

This is broad, I guess, but *some* questions which come to mind:

1. Suppose $f'$ is injective. Then we can remove the quotations from function. Is $\delta_x$ continuous? Differentiable? How does imposing certain conditions affect its behaviour(say $C^{\infty})$? [For some functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156031/in-mean-value-theorem-does-the-mean-value-vary-continuously?noredirect=1&lq=1) (which don't meet the injectivity requirement) it can be made discontinuous. How discontinuous can it be?
2. Suppose $f'$ is not injective; in this case, $\delta_x$ may be multivalued. In particular, it is a *set* of values. Are there circumstances in which this "set" is ever useful? For example, a reasonable sounding conjecture is that if $\delta_x$ is a set with positive Lebesgue measure, $f$ is linear almost everywhere in $(c,x)$.

Comment: If $f\in C^1$ and $f'$ is injective, then $f'$ admits an inverse and so we can express $\delta(x)=(f')^{-1}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\right)$, which is continuous and differentiable.